# NGINX Downloading php files but files excutes when i use https

Tags: php, nginx, ssl-certificate

php files at my server executing well when i am using https://
but it start downloading .php files as code when i use http:// in browser.
i have installed lets encrypt ssl on server.

here is my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file.

```js
server {
    server_name  localhost;


    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi.conf;
 }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    if ($host = localhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = localhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    if ($host = localhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 if ($host = localhost) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

i have changed domain to localhost due to security reasons.
can somebody tell me what is wrong. none solution worked. :(

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is port 80 and HTTPS is port 443.  You need to to have

```
listen 80;
```

in a server block that is telling nginx to pass the request on to PHP.  The configuration below is in your server block with `listen 443` and thats why HTTPS is executing the php file instead of downloading it

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi.conf;
 }
```

Comment: location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi.conf;
 }

i have added this code to listen 80; block still it is not executing php files.

Comment: you also have 2 server blocks that are listening on port 80.  You only want 1

Answer (score -2):

No solution worked so i force redirected all http:// traffic to https://

Comment: Your config is almost impossible to read because it's messy, how are you capable of producing such bad code? That's what happens when you copypaste blindly without understanding what you're doing. Suggested solution works, you're just too incompetent to apply the solution because it's not copypaste.